# Mongo DB make connection outside of post?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database

I am using MongoDB to insert a record into the database, every time the post method is called. I know I do not want to connect to the db inside of the post function every time, but this is giving me errors? How can I correct this?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Wedding'
var db = function() {
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
  if (!err){
  return db;
  }
 });
}

app.post('/rsvp', function (req, res) {
 var item ={
  name: req.body.name,
  attending: req.body.attending,
  };
 insertItem(item);
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/confirm.html'));
})

function insertItem(item){
 db.collection('rsvpList').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
 assert.equal(null, err);
})
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object function () { 
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){ 
if (!err){ 
 return db; 
 } 
}); 
} has no method 'collection'
at insertItem (C:\Users\A587092\Documents\weddingWebsite\server.js:53:8)
at app.listen.host (C:\Users\A587092\Documents\weddingWebsite\server.js:38:4)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\A587092\Documents\weddingWebsite\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of headaches, use the Mongoose module.  It helps a lot with both connection management and schema / validation stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `db` does not point to the Mongo instance rather to a function!

Try this -

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Wedding'
var db;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, connectedDB){
  if (!err){
      db = connectedDB;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't simply return a value from an asynchronous method:

You should use a **callback** function:

```
var connectDb = function(url, cb) {
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if ( err ) {
      cb( err );
    }
    cb(null, db);
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
function insertItem(item) {
  connectDb(url, function(error, db) {
    if ( error ) {
      throw error;
    }
    db.collection('rsvpList').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
    });
  });
}
```

---

Or a **promise**:

```
var connectDb = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
      if ( err ) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(db);
    });
  });
};
```

**Usage**:

```
function insertItem(item) {
  connectDb(url)
    .then(function(db) {
      db.collection('rsvpList').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      throw err;
    });
}
```

I change the function name from `db` to `connectDb` because we want to connect to db and then doing something after connecting. and this way your code reads well.

Also note that here also your `insertItem` function doing an asynchronous task so if you need the `result` outside of this function you should implement a similar approach, i leave it to you ;)